# Page Object Model or JavaScript testing alternatives?

Tags: javascript, webdriver, cucumberjs

Is the Page Object Model still the best way to automate web applications ?

For me the Screenplay pattern seems a nicer way to manage it.

Or using JavaScript alternatives like Acceptance Testing with Cucumber.js & WebdriverIO for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question makes it sound like there is only one answer, but actually you can merge these all together if you code it correctly.

**Page Object Model**

This is good for separation of the elements on the page from the rest of your code. If implemented correctly, a change on the page can be corrected for all scenarios using that page by simply changing one line in the POM.

```
nextButton.click();
fullName.sendKeys("John Doe");
```

**Screenplay Pattern**

This is good for separation of actions that occur on the different pages, the different workflows.

```
james.attemptsTo(
   goToTheNextPage(),
   fillOutHisDetails()
);
```

If the journey has workflow that is slightly changed, the idea is that you can simply reorder the Screenplay pattern, or remove the actions that are no longer necessary.
In the example above, if the business were to decide that the registration form should be a single page instead of multiple, it would make more sense to delete this single line:

```
goToTheNextPage(),
```

instead of deleting the 2 that I would have put in:

```
driver.findElement({css:"#next"}).click();
driver.findElement({css:"#registrationDetails"});
```

**CucumberJS + WebdriverIO**

This is good to portray the information of a scenario in pure business language.

```
Scenario: I am filling out the registration form
   Given I am a new user
     And I want to register for an account
   When I fill out the registration form
   Then I should be able to log in
```

**Merging them**

If you want truely human readable code, you can merge all 3 of these.

You have your feature file at business level language.
You have your step definitions written with the Screenplay pattern in mind.
You have the Screenplay pattern steps written with the Page Object Model.

This may seem like a lot of layers, but it means that the business will be able to understand the scenarios, the testers and developers looking back over the code will understand the workflow of a certain journey, and looking further into the code on debugging will allow the tester to change the element values across multiple journeys by only changing one line of code.